# Best way to loop this situation?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of `div`s, and I'm trying to get certain info in each of them. The `div` classes are the same so I'm not sure how I would go about this.

I have tried `for` loops but have been getting various errors

Code to get list of divs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://sneakernews.com/release-dates/'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
soup1 = soup.find("div", {'class': 'popular-releases-block'})
soup1 = str(soup1.find("div", {'class': 'row'}))
soup1 = soup1.split('</div>')
print(soup1)
```

Code I want to loop for each item in the `soup1` list:

```
linkinfo = soup1.find('a')['href']
date = str(soup1.find('span'))
name = soup1.find('a')
non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
date = non_decimal.sub('', date)
name = str(name)
name = re.sub('</a>', '', name)
link, name = name.split('>')
link = re.sub('<a href="', '', link)
link = re.sub('"', '', link)
name = name.split('    ')
name = str(name[-1])
date = str(date)
link = str(link)
print(link)
print(name)
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the URL you posted above, I imagine you are interested in something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://sneakernews.com/release-dates/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col lg-2 sm-3 popular-releases-box'})

for tag in tags:
    link = tag.find('a').get('href')
    print(link)
    print(tag.text)
    #Anything else you want to do
```

If you are using the  `BeautifulSoup` library, then you do not need `regex` to try to parse through HTML tags. Instead, use the handy methods that accompany `BeautifulSoup`. If you would like to apply a `regex` to the text output from the tags you locate via `BeautifulSoup` to accomplish a more specific task, then that would be reasonable.

Comment: woah.. yea, exactly what i was going for lol.. mind explaining the "tag" + "tags" part? i dont understand, thank you :)

Comment: Absolutely. `for tag in tags` simply loops through the list `tags` that is created in the previous line using `soup.find_all`. Note that `soup.find_all` will return a list or `[]` if it cannot locate any matches, while `soup.find` will return a single match or `None` if it cannot locate any matches. You also could write `for i in tags` or `for t in tags`, it's up to you, just wanted to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: but whats representing "tag"? wondering because im trying to get the link also

Comment: I think you need to read into the basics of for loops. `tag` simply represents an individual item inside of the list `tags`, which is why you don't necessarily have to use the name `tag` as I mentioned previously. It can be anything you want, since you are iterating through the list `tags`. Think of it like literally saying "For each tag in the list tags" --> `for tag in tags`

Comment: See my edit for the link. Technically, you do not need to include `.find('a')`, but I did so for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to loop your code for each item within a list. 
An example of this:

```
my_list = ["John", "Fred", "Tom"]

for name in my_list:
    print(name)
```

This will loop for each name that is in `my_list` and print out each item (reffered to here as `name` in the list). You could do something similar with your code:

```
for item in soup1:
    # perform some action
```

Comment: I tried this, but i keep getting errors based on the loop code, for example: linkinfo = soup1.find('a')['href'] ... what would i put for "soup1" in this scenario?